# Python os.setgid is picking a wrong group id

Tags: python

Below is the portion of a code process that I am debugging. The script makes use of a subprocess module to invoke oracle sqlplus. I am setting gid before uid, but still sqlplus is started with the group id that the user (oracle) is not even associated with.

```
def demote(self, user_gid, user_uid):
    def result():
        os.setgid(user_gid)
        os.setuid(user_uid)
        a= os.getgid()
        b =os.getuid()
        print (a, b)
        print(os.getgroups())

    return result


def run_sqlplus(self):
    pw_record = pwd.getpwnam('oracle')
    user_gid = pw_record.pw_gid
    user_uid = pw_record.pw_uid
    print(user_gid)
    print(user_uid)


    p = subprocess.Popen(["sqlplus", "/ as sysdba"], preexec_fn=CONFIG.demote(user_gid, user_uid),
                         stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                         env={'ORACLE_SID': '{0}'.format(vinstance_name), 'ORACLE_HOME': '{0}'.format(ORACLE_HOME),
                              'PATH': '{0}/bin'.format(ORACLE_HOME)})
    (stdout, stderr) = p.communicate(sqlplus_script.encode('utf-8'))
    stdout_lines = stdout.decode('utf-8').split("\n")

    return stdout_lines

sqlplus_script = """ 
STARTUP NOMOUNT;
exit;
```

Any resolution is highly appreciated.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

I ended up modifying the script as below and it works like a charm:

p = subprocess.Popen(["sqlplus", "/ as sysdba", "@{0}/admin/{1}/Scripts/Create.sql".format(ORACLE_BASE,vdb_unique_name)], preexec_fn=CONFIG.demote(user_gid, user_uid),
                             stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                             stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                             env={'ORACLE_SID': '{0}'.format(vinstance_name), 'ORACLE_HOME': '{0}'.format(ORACLE_HOME),
                                  'PATH': '{0}/bin'.format(ORACLE_HOME)})